# UIWebView: change view title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a storyboard with a UIViewController. Inside this view, I've placed a custom UIWebView. In the code in my custom webview I would like to change the title in navigation control of its outer UIViewController.

I've tried to call the superview in the webview, but that just gives me an UIView. How can I, from this webview, change the title in the UIViewController?

Comment: You don't. You should probably do it in the view controller itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you do:

1. In the `UIViewController`, I assume that you've got some code setup to represent this UIWebView? Add the `UIWebView` as a property of the `UIViewController` (Don't forget the IBOutlet part!)

   `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;`
2. In the storyboard, link the `UIWebView` to the `UIViewController`.
3. Make the `UIViewController` a `UIWebViewDelegate` (see documentation [`here`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate))
4. In the UIViewController, implement the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method. In this method, the UIWebView will let the UIViewController know when it's done loading the page. You can then assign the title of the webview to the UINavigationController's title with this code:

   `NSString *pageTitle=[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
   [self.navigationItem setTitle:pageTitle];`

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to your UIViewController, to get a reference to its NavigationItem.

Try:

```
[[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"new title"];
```

(where `self` is the view controller)